aiohttp starts throwing WinError 64 suddenly
My program has stopped working and throwing WinError 64 after downloading > 800,000 files in different batches. The requested urls are active, so the network location is still live.
To debug, I ran print statement after each command in the subroutine. Seems like, the program stops working after session.get() statement.
I have used asyncio.as_completed() to execute the coroutines.
Code Snippet
async def binary_coroutines(sem, dl_file_name, url):
    print(f"Working 1")
    async with sem:
        print(f"Working 2")
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            print(f"Working 3")
            async with session.get(url) as resp:
                print(f"Working 4")
                r = await resp.read()
                print(f"Working 5")
                dl_file_path = os.path.join(REL_DOC_DIR, dl_file_name)
                with open(dl_file_path, 'wb') as file_pointer:
                    file_pointer.write(r)
                return dl_file_name

Error Received
Number of documents to be downloaded: 5
Working 1
Working 2
Working 3
Working 1
Working 2
Working 3
Working 1
Working 2
Working 3
Working 1
Working 2
Working 3
Working 1
Working 2
Working 3
[WinError 64] The specified network name is no longer available
[WinError 64] The specified network name is no longer available
[WinError 64] The specified network name is no longer available
[WinError 64] The specified network name is no longer available
[WinError 64] The specified network name is no longer available
Time Taken:  0.015347826480865478  minutes

As you can see Working 4 and Working 5 are not getting printed. Hence, the program entered the Try/Except block and started printing the error code.

I would consider the possibility that the computer is simply running out of memory.  Are you storing something in variables?  There is almost no way that the logic of your code begins to fail after working correctly 800,000 times.  But if you're building a data structure while downloading the files, the computer MUST eventually run out of storage.

Running out of memory is very unlikely, although I considered it initially. In fact, I was considering if the remote server was closing the socket due to large http requests. I have 16GB RAM. Further, I ran the program always in batches. The batch size varied between 20,000 - 150,000 records. However, it is not even running for 5 records now. I even tried with a single record as well.

this seems to have to do with operating system specific network limits. What system are you on?

I am on Windows 11. Why would there be limit for as low as 1 or 5 requests when it worked for few tens/hundreds of thousands request?
